# React Native: null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.displayErrors')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I had a fully functioning Android application and now I am getting this error:

`null is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.displayErrors')` which is referencing this line of code here:

```
_getErrors = () => {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      return {
        ...this.state.validationErrors,
        ...this.props.validationErrors
      };
    }
    return {};
  };
```

This is the full file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import DetailsConfirmationForm from "auth/components/DetailsConfirmationForm";
import {
  firstNameChanged,
  lastNameChanged,
  prefixChanged,
  suffixChanged,
  stateChanged
} from "auth/registrationActions";
import regex from "utils/helpers/regex";
import { prefixes, suffixes } from "enums/dropdownOptions";

export class DetailsConfirmation extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    firstName: PropTypes.string,
    firstNameChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    lastName: PropTypes.string,
    lastNameChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    prefix: PropTypes.string,
    prefixChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    registeredUser: PropTypes.object,
    state: PropTypes.string,
    stateChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    suffix: PropTypes.string,
    suffixChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    validationErrors: PropTypes.object
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { personalDetails, personalAddress } = this.props.registeredUser;
    console.log(this.props.registeredUser);
    if (personalDetails) {
      this.props.firstNameChanged(personalDetails.firstName);
      this.props.lastNameChanged(personalDetails.lastName);
      this.props.suffixChanged(personalDetails.suffix);
      this.props.prefixChanged(personalDetails.prefix);
    }

    if (personalAddress && personalAddress.stateCode) {
      this.props.stateChanged(personalAddress.stateCode);
    }

    const { params = {} } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const { displayAlert = true } = params;

    this.state = {
      validationErrors: {},
      displayErrors: false,
      titleName: personalDetails && personalDetails.firstName,
      displayAlert
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      this._validate(nextProps);
    }
  }

  _validate = props => {
    const { prefix, state, firstName, lastName, suffix } = props;
    const validPrefixes = prefixes.map(p => p.value);
    const validSuffixes = suffixes.map(p => p.value);
    const validationErrors = {
      prefix:
        prefix && prefix.trim() && validPrefixes.includes(prefix)
          ? ""
          : "Is Required",
      state: state && state.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      firstName: firstName && firstName.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      lastName: lastName && lastName.trim() ? "" : "Is Required",
      suffix:
        !suffix || validSuffixes.includes(suffix) ? "" : "Select an option"
    };

    const nameRegexErrorMessage =
      "Only letters, hyphens and periods are allowed.";
    if (validationErrors.firstName === "" && !regex.userName.test(firstName)) {
      validationErrors.firstName = nameRegexErrorMessage;
    }
    if (validationErrors.lastName === "" && !regex.userName.test(lastName)) {
      validationErrors.lastName = nameRegexErrorMessage;
    }

    const fullErrors = {
      ...validationErrors,
      ...this.props.validationErrors
    };

    const isValid = Object.keys(fullErrors).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (fullErrors[curr] !== "") {
        return false;
      }

      return acc;
    }, true);

    if (isValid) {
      this.setState({ validationErrors: {} });
      //register
    } else {
      this.setState({ validationErrors, displayErrors: true });
    }

    return isValid;
  };

  _navigate = () => {
    const isValid = this._validate(this.props);
    if (isValid) {
      if (this.props.registeredUser.organization) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("CompleteAccount");
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("AskForMembership");
      }
    }
  };

  _getErrors = () => {
    if (this.state.displayErrors) {
      return {
        ...this.state.validationErrors,
        ...this.props.validationErrors
      };
    }
    return {};
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DetailsConfirmationForm
        {...this.state}
        {...this.props}
        navigate={this._navigate}
        validationErrors={this._getErrors()}
      />
    );
  }
}

const mapsStateToProps = ({ registrations }) => {
  return {
    ...registrations.accountData,
    validationErrors: registrations.validationErrors,
    registeredUser: registrations.registeredUser
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapsStateToProps,
  {
    firstNameChanged,
    lastNameChanged,
    prefixChanged,
    suffixChanged,
    stateChanged
  }
)(DetailsConfirmation);
```

Is this a scoping issue? The `if` statement does not have access to `displayErrors` outside of `_getErrors` function? If so, how in the world did this work for several weeks before?

I tried placing:

```
this.state = {
   validationErrors: {},
   displayErrors: false,
   titleName: personalDetails && personalDetails.firstName,
   displayAlert
};
```

inside the `constructor(props)` function where I believe this belongs, but then I get a ton of other problems regarding the variables in it such as `personalDetails` and `displayAlert` not being defined as variables. The biggest pain being that `displayAlert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting `this.state` in your constructor you will need to destructure `props` to get the values you need similar to what is happening in `componentDidMount`. I would remove the setting of initial state values from `componentDidMount` altogether.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { personalDetails, personalAddress } = props.registeredUser;
    const { params = {} } = props.navigation.state;
    const { displayAlert = true } = params;

    this.state = {
      validationErrors: {},
      displayErrors: false,
      titleName: personalDetails && personalDetails.firstName,
      displayAlert
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { personalDetails, personalAddress } = this.props.registeredUser;
    console.log(this.props.registeredUser);
    if (personalDetails) {
      this.props.firstNameChanged(personalDetails.firstName);
      this.props.lastNameChanged(personalDetails.lastName);
      this.props.suffixChanged(personalDetails.suffix);
      this.props.prefixChanged(personalDetails.prefix);
    }

    if (personalAddress && personalAddress.stateCode) {
      this.props.stateChanged(personalAddress.stateCode);
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem or how `this.state` is getting set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line in **DetailsConfirmationForm** component

```
validationErrors={this._getErrors()}
```

**You are calling function instead of passing** .

**Try this**

```
validationErrors={this._getErrors}
```